# Is sscanf destructive?

Tags: c, getline, scanf

The first call to printf below prints out my line.

The second call to printf prints out whitespace.

What's going on?

```
while (getline(&line, &size, config_file) != -1) {

    printf("line: %s\n", line);

    /* check to see if this line is a comment */
    char marker[1];
    sscanf(line, "%1s", marker);

    printf("line: %s\n", line); 

    if (marker[0] == '#') {
    .
    .
```

Comment: That should be `char marker[2];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sscanf(line, "%1s", marker);
```

Apart from the one character you did specify it also stores a `\0` terminator in `marker`. It's obviously undefined but my guess is that `\0` overwrites `line`.

In other words `marker` needs to be at least 2 characters wide to store a one character string.

Comment: oh wow, of course, perfect example of silent memory corruption